# How to check whether system has some header file using bazel build?

Tags: bazel

What I want to find is the existence of some platform specific header file.
For example, in source code there will be some #ifdef section like this.

```
#ifdef HAVE_XXX_H
//...do something
#else
//...do other thing
#endif
```

In Autoconf or Cmake, there exists dedicated macro or command for detecting platform specific header file or definition. So, I can easily set 'HAVE_XXX_H' as 1 or 0 according to the result of that macro.

Using bazel, how can I achieve this kind of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the header is always present on a particular platform, use [`select()`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) as elaborated by László.

If you actually need to detect the header at the build time, you will have to implement a custom [repository_rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html#repository-rules) that will query the system and will generate a workspace with a header defining the macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`select()`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select).

Example: [`select()` in `cc_library.srcs`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/2049c84eaffc6b16498eecb95d36318652b0275c/src/main/cpp/util/BUILD#L34). You can do the same in `cc_library.hdrs`.